# Reportlab table VALIGN with large text font

Tags: python, reportlab

I'm fairly new to reportlab but pretty quickly started to generate some nice reports with it in conjunction with matplotlib. Now I'm faced with the problem of presenting data in a table rather then a chart so I decided to look into reportlab Tables to do it as it seemed the right tool for the job.
At first everything was going smoothly but when I started to customized the table style to fit my needs VALIGN seems to behave strangely.
When I have a small fontsize it produces the expected result and the text appears in the middle of the cell but when I increase the fontsize it start to drift to the bottom of the cell. What is the reason for this kind of behaviour? I have looked at the documentation in regards to Tables on reportlab but haven't found much when it comes to VALIGN so no luck there.

Here is the code that I'm currently running and is producing a non middle text in cells despite having middle VALIGN:

```
    tableData = [
                ['', 'Seg-Sex\n\n9h-18h', 'Seg-Sex\n\n18h-9h', 'Seg-Sex', 'Sab-Dom'],
                ['Secção 1', 'XXX kWh', 'XXX kWh', 'XXX kWh', 'XXX kWh'],  
                ['Secção 2', 'XXX kWh', 'XXX kWh', 'XXX kWh', 'XXX kWh'],  
                ['Secção 3', 'XXX kWh', 'XXX kWh', 'XXX kWh', 'XXX kWh'],  
                ['Total', 'XXX kWh', 'XXX kWh', 'XXX kWh', 'XXX kWh']  
            ]

    t = Table(tableData, colWidths=100, rowHeights=30, vAlign='middle')

    tableStyle = TableStyle([
        ('VALIGN', (0,0), (-1,-1), 'MIDDLE'),
        ('ALIGN', (0,0), (-1,-1), 'CENTER'),
        
        ('BACKGROUND',(1,1),(-2,-2),colors.HexColor(0x0039570F, hasAlpha=True)),
        ('BACKGROUND',(1,-1),(-1,-1),colors.HexColor(0x000000AB, hasAlpha=True)),
        ('TEXTCOLOR',(1,1),(-1,-2),colors.HexColor(0x003957)),
        ('INNERGRID',(0,0),(-1,-1),10,colors.red),
        #('BOX',(0,0),(-1,-1),1,colors.white),
        ('FONTNAME', (0,0), (-1,-1), 'Calibri'),
        ('FONTSIZE', (0,0), (-1,-1), 18),
        #('LEADING', (0,0), (-1,-1), 100),
        ('LEFTPADDING', (0,0), (-1,-1), 0),
        ('RIGHTPADDING', (0,0), (-1,-1), 0),
        ('BOTTOMPADDING', (0,0), (-1,-1), 0),
        ('TOPPADDING', (0,0), (-1,-1), 0),
    ])

    tableWidth, tableHeight = t.wrapOn(my_canvas, width, height)
    tableY = subSubTitleY-50-tableHeight
    tableX = width/2-tableWidth/2

    t.setStyle(tableStyle)
    t.drawOn(my_canvas, tableX, tableY)
```

All cells in the table have their text offset to the bottom when using this example even though VALIGN is set to 'middle'. This does no appear to be the issue when the text size is smaller for instance with: ('FONTSIZE', (0,0), (-1,-1), 10) instead of 18.

Here is a sample picture of the result:
[image]

One possible solution I though of was to assemble the table with "drawStrings" and other canvas supported methods but wanted to try this solution first.
Thanks in advance for any help regarding this issue.